# Import a still installed PyPi package in MinGW environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, mingw, python-import

I have problems doing `import` of packages I installed via `pip3` in a **MinGW** environment. The *module is not found* but it is installed.

```
Buhtzy@Buhtzy MINGW64 ~
$ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, May 28 2019, 08:37:07)  [GCC 8.3.0 64 bit
(AMD64)] on win32 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for
more information.
>>> import colorlog  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colorlog'
>>> exit()  

Buhtzy@Buhtzy MINGW64 ~
$ pip3 install colorlog
Requirement already satisfied: colorlog
in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (4.0.2)
```

It is a *MinGW 64bit* on a *Windows 10* machine.

Some background informations.

The `pip3` binary

```
$ which pip3
/usr/bin/pip3
```

Which is a script with this content

```
$ cat /usr/bin/pip3
#!/usr/bin/python3.exe
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip._internal import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

`sys.path` is

```
>>> print('\n'.join(sys.path))
C:/Users/Buhtzy/ownCloud/PROJEKTE/naoqi/lib
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python37.zip
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.7
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

Python3 also is not able to install `pip` itself as a module.

```
$ python3 -m pip install colorlog
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/python3.exe: No module named pip
```

I tried to install `pip` from *PyPi*

```
$ pip3 install -U pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages (19.1.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand *MinGW* but it looks like that Python**3** is the default here.

So `python` is **Version 3.7.3** by default.

All *PyPi* packages I installed with `pip3` are able to load via `python -m` or directly inside the `python` interpreter shell.